# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are greater than $0$. Show that $\gcd(X,Y)$ is $1$ iff $\gcd(X^m,Y^m)= 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

#### Problem

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are greater than $0$. Show that $\gcd(X,Y)$ is $1$ iff $\gcd(X^m,Y^m)= 1$.

Please help with the above. I have no idea what's going on.
An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\gcd(X,Y)=1$. We show that $\gcd(X^m,Y^m)=1$. Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(X^m,Y^m)=d\gt 1$. Then there is a prime $p$ that divides $d$. 
So $p$ divides $X^m$ and $p$ divides $Y^m$.

Recall that if a prime $p$ divides a product, then $p$ divides at least one of the terms. So $p$ divides $X$ and $p$ divides $Y$. This contradicts the fact that $\gcd(X,Y)=1$.

Next we need to show that if $\gcd(X^m,Y^m)=1$ then $\gcd(X,Y)=1$. The argument is similar to the one above, but easier, and is left to you.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a simple explanation based on prime factorization: for any integer $N$, we will have
$$N=p_1\times...\times{p_m}$$

So $\gcd(X,Y)=1$ iff $X,Y$ have no common prime factors.

> **Proof** From the assumption, we have that $X^m,Y^m$ have no common prime factors. And same are the $X,Y$. Then easily $\gcd(X,Y)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,\cal P(n) = $ set of primes factors of $\,n.\,$ By *unique factorization*, $\,\cal \color{#c00}{P(n^k) = \cal P(n)}\,$ for $\,k\ge 1,\,$ so

$$\gcd(x,y)=1\iff \cal P(x)\cap \cal P(y) = \emptyset\color{#c00}\iff P(x^m)\cap \cal P(y^m) =\emptyset \iff \gcd(x^m,y^m) =\rm 1$$